# cs50 pset1 water.c I am getting error while compiling

Tags: c, cs50

following code is throwing compiling error. I am new to programming and so dont know what else to do. I did as taught in the class but cant get it right. cam anyone please help me solve it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
   int y; 
do
{
   printf("Minutes: ");
   int Minutes = get_int();
}
while(Minutes< 0);

y= Minutes * 12;
printf("Bottles: %i\n", y);
}
```

it is throwing following error:

```
water.c:10:8: error: unused variable 'Minutes' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
   int Minutes = get_int();
   ^
water.c:12:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Minutes'
while(Minutes< 0);
  ^
water.c:14:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Minutes'
y= Minutes * 12;
   ^
    3 errors generated.
make: *** [water] Error 1
```

Comment: `int Minutes;` move to before do-while loop.

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *scoping*.

Comment: The error pretty much says it all.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `Minutes` in the scope of the `do` block. That means it can only be used within that same scope - ie. between the `{}` enclosing the block.

You are however using the variable outside of that scope (twice in fact).

Instead, define `Minutes` before the `do` loop :

```
int Minutes = 0;
do {
    printf("Minutes: ");
    Minutes = get_int();
}
while(Minutes< 0);
```

This puts it in the scope of the `main` function body, so it can be used anywhere in the `main` function (after its definition).

Comment: It is showing following error: water.c:10:8: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-    Wshadow]
       int Minutes = get_int();
       ^
    water.c:6:11: note: previous declaration is here
       int y, Minutes=0; 
          ^
    water.c:10:8: error: unused variable 'Minutes' [-Werror,-Wunused-    variable]
       int Minutes = get_int();
       ^
    2 errors generated.
make: *** [water] Error 1
~/workspace/pset1/ $

Comment: The new error is because you still have `int Minutes = get_int();` in the loop meaning `Minutes` is redeclared -- it should be `Minutes = get_int();`.

Answer (score 0):

`int Minutes` is declared local to the loop body, meaning that the loop condition `while(Minutes< 0)` has no idea what "Minutes" is.

Simply move the declaration out of the loop, above it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("minutes: ");
    int minutes = get_int();

    printf("bottles: ");
    int bottles = get_int();

    printf("%i\n divided %i\n is %i\n", minutes, bottles, minutes / bottles);
}
```